# Alembic/Flask-Migrate not detecting after_create events

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I have a simple Flask-SQLAlchemy model (with event listener to create trigger):

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Confirm(db.Model):
  created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(), nullable=False)
  modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(), onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp(), nullable=False)
  id = db.Column(db.String(36), primary_key=True) 

class ConfirmOld(db.Model):
  orig_created = db.Column(db.DateTime)
  orig_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime)
  orig_id = db.Column(db.String(36))

confirm_delete = DDL('''\
CREATE TRIGGER confirm_delete 
BEFORE DELETE
  ON confirm FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO confirm_old ( orig_created, orig_modified, orig_id )
    VALUES ( OLD.created, OLD.modified, OLD.id );
  END;
''')

event.listen(Confirm.__table__, 'after_create', confirm_delete)
```

When I run Alembic migrate and upgrade, the TRIGGER is not created (in MySQL). However, it *is* created and works properly when I use db.create_all().

Is it possible to get Alembic / Flask-Migrate to create and manage my triggers (i.e., custom DDL that is run on after_create events)?

Comment: Not sure why the trigger doesn't hit when you go through Alembic, but I can tell you if you are working with migrations, it is much better to include the trigger creation in the migration script instead of in a SQLAlchemy event.

Comment: That sounds good - is there a way to keep track of the current state of active DDL? By that, I mean keeping track of each step in the migration history (which is what you propose) together with the currently active state of triggers (or any DDL for that matter)?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. By fact of having the migration scripts you have a very well defined schema history. Recall that migration scripts have upgrade and downgrade functions, this allows you to jump to any point in the history of your database schema.

Comment: Alembic does not autodetect custom DDL. You should take a look at the [Replaceable Objects](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#replaceable-objects) section of the docs which outlines how to make managing triggers, functions, and views easier.

Comment: @univerio, that link is now dead, but this one (currently) works: [Replacable Objects](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/cookbook.html#replaceable-objects)

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same issue tried a solution with Replacable object but didn't work:

I manage to make it work by editing the migration script and execute the trigger creation query.

Here are the step:

- Run `flask db migrate -m 'adding custom trigger on table x`  it will generate a migration script for you under version sub-folder of migration folder.
- check the folder created under version and edit it like this :

create your trigger query like this :

in the file :

```
trigger = '''
CREATE TRIGGER confirm_delete
BEFORE DELETE
ON confirm FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO confirm_old ( orig_created, orig_modified, orig_id )
VALUES ( OLD.created, OLD.modified, OLD.id );
END;
'''
```

in the upgrade method :

add this line :

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###

    # ### end Alembic commands ###

    ### add your queries here execute
    op.execute(trigger)
```

If you run `flask db upgrade` it will execute the query and update the database

to downgrade the database add this in the downgrade method:

```
def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
    op.execute('drop trigger if exists confirm_delete on confirm cascade;')
```

If you check your database change will be applied .

PS : The more elegant solution should be what is suggest [here](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/cookbook.html#replaceable-objects)

with Replaceable object , tried it but It doesn't work may be my alembic is not update .

Here is how the solution should looks like:

create a ReplaceableObjects class :

```
class ReplaceableObject(object):
    def __init__(self, name, sqltext):
        self.name = name
        self.sqltext = sqltext
```

instantiate it with your query statement.

```
delete_trigger = ReplaceableObject('delete_trigger', trigger)
```

Update your upgrade and downgrade function like this :

```
def upgrade():
    op.create_sp(delete_trigger)


def downgrade():
    op.drop_sp(delete_trigger)
```

Hope it will helps others...

Answer (score 0):

in Flask the listen is ignored.

Fixed this by using Table instead.

```
def after_create_table_handler(table: Table, conn: Connection, **kwargs):
   pass
event.listen(Table, 'after_create', after_create_table_handler)
```